# Discord.js timeout timer not working and delete right away

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to send a embed then after 5 seconds ins gonna get deleted. I haved tried this.

```
 client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.content === '&unlock') {
        await message.channel
            .permissionOverwrites.edit(message.guild.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true })
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [unlockembed] }).then(message => message.delete({setTimeout: 5000}))
    }
})
```

But the timer not working and the message get deleted right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for you and employs the new method of delayed message.delete()

```js
 client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.content === '&unlock') {
        const channel = message.channel;
        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.guild.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true })
        message.channel.send({ 
            embeds: [unlockembed] 
        }).then(msg => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                msg.delete()
            }, 5000);
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous to v13 Messages had a `timeout` option for `.delete()`, however you now need to use a `setTimeout()` function.

```js
setTimeout(message.delete, 5000);
```

Comment: thx but this error come up 
Error [CHANNEL_NOT_CACHED]: Could not find the channel where this message came from in the cache!